# To access the text area in the html rendered using Iframe which itself is loaded withing a cshtml page

Tags: image, iframe, textarea

I have an iframe loaded within a Cshtml page. The Iframe contains an html form. i need to add an image in front of each text area of the form when the main page(cshtml page) is loaded. Have tried a lot of things but nothing has worked as such. Below is the code i am trying:

```
$("#iframe").ready(function() {
    $.each($('input[type=text],textarea'), function() {

        var idOfCurrentElement =  $(this).attr('id');
        var classNameOfCurrentElement =  $(this).attr('class');
        var visibilityOfCurrentElement = $(this).css('visibility'); 

        if(classNameOfCurrentElement != "hidden" && visibilityOfCurrentElement == "visible")        
            $("<img src='~/images/pic' alt='Pic'>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must access iframe content, not your page.

```
$("#iframe").ready(function() {
      $.each($('#iframe').contents().find('input[type=text],textarea'), function() {
         var $thatButton =  $(this);
         var idOfCurrentElement = thatButton .attr('id');
         var classNameOfCurrentElement =  thatButton ).attr('class');
         var visibilityOfCurrentElement = thatButton .css('visibility'); 

     if(classNameOfCurrentElement != "hidden" && visibilityOfCurrentElement == "visible")        
         //do what you want.
      });
});
```

Comment: thank you so much! this works. but the button i am trying to append to each text area does not gets appended.                                                         if(classNameOfCurrentElement != "hidden" && visibilityOfCurrentElement == "visible")        
        $(this).append($('<button>click</button>'));

Comment: You cannot append button to input or textarea. Also be careful using $(this). This is which this? You should know. I updated the answer for determining input or textarea using var $thatButton =  $(this). You can use after or before instead of append for input or textarea like $thatButton .after($('<button>click</button>'))